# The source-side-opposite of the arrow category

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

Given a category $C$, is there a name for the following category:

- $\mathrm{Obj}(D) = \left\{ (x, y, f) \middle| x, y \in \mathrm{Obj}(C), f \in C(x, y) \right\}$
- $D((x, y, f), (x', y', f')) = \left\{ (g, h) \middle| g \in C(x', x), h \in C(y, y'), h \circ f \circ g = f' \right\}$

This is, if you want, the final category $D$ that has a covariant functor $P : D \to C$, a contravariant functor $Q : D \to C$ and a dinatural transformation $Q \to P$.

If this is a known construct, then I am also interested in higher-dimensional generalizations (i.e. if $C$ is an $n$-category, I would like an $n$-category $D$ with similar properties).

Comment: Isn't this the twisted arrow category?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Zhen Lin suggests, what you are describing is called the "twisted arrow category" $C_\#$ in Mac Lane's *Categories for the Working Mathematician* (see exercise IX.6.3, p.227).  It goes by other names as well: for example "category of factorizations".  A quick way of defining $C_\#$ is as the category of elements of $hom_C : C^{op} \times C \to \mathrm{Set}$ (in particular, the pairing of the projection functors is a discrete fibration $C_\# \to C^{op} \times C$). You can find more discussion (including higher dimensional generalizations) [at the nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/twisted+arrow+category).

Comment: Great, thanks! Are you aware of an occasion where someone applied this operation repeatedly, using e.g. $C_{\# \# \# \#}$?

Answer (score 2):

The term **"twisted arrow category"** was used by *Dwyer* and *Kan* in 1983, but this is maybe not the origin. However you see, the construction is strongly related to simplicial sets, aka $(\infty,1)$-categories.

Often its homotopy type is considered. For example in a proof of *Quillen's Theorem A* (and *B*). Along these lines its referred as **"subdivision category"**. This name should reveal a lot of material. I also vaguely remember a double application somewhere in this context..

As Noam pointed out, you can get this category by applying the (contravariant) [Grothendieck-construction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+construction) to the $Hom$-functor. This idea does generalize to higher categories, but I am not aware of any references.

[Dwyer,Kan,'83 - Function complexes for diagrams of simplicial sets]